# Floating/Aligning Responsive Form Button Next to Search Box

Tags: forms, button, responsive, inline

I'm working on a new template and have my search form displaying exactly the way I want it across devices, with the search box to the left and the button floating right next to it to the right. Unfortunately, that causes validation errors since the form is separated in divs.

I've been trying different methods to fix this including display:inline, span, etc. but am at a loss. When I take it out of the divs, it just ends up stacking instead of the button displaying next to the search box, when it should only be stacking on screens 480px or smaller. I feel I'm missing something obvious here. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out thanks to [W3Schools Inline Form tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_inline_form.asp)